# Insert element and move elements after in vector

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a linked list using a vector to hold (And I know I shouldn't use a vector). I'm trying to implement a function to insert a node a position `x` and move all elements after `x` but for some reason it just takes the element originally at `x` and over writes all remaining elements with this value.

This is the function I am having problem with:

```
//Insert element at x index
void LinkedList::insertAt(int x, int data) {
    Node* tempNode = new Node();
    Node* currentNode = vecList[x];
    Node* nextNode = vecList[x + 1];
    Node* previousNode = vecList[x - 1];

    if(x == count) {
        push_back(tempNode, data);
        return;
    }
    else {
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++){
            vecList[x + 1]->next = vecList[x]->next;   // tranfer the address of 'temp->next' to 'temp'
            vecList[x + 1]->data = vecList[x]->data;
            if (vecList[x] == NULL){break;}
        }
        tempNode->data = data;
        tempNode->previous = previousNode;
        tempNode->next = nextNode;
        tempNode->id = x+1;

        vecList[x] = tempNode;
        vecList[x - 1]->next = tempNode; //Point previous node to this node
    }
}//Adds Node but replaces orignal Node
```

It places the value passed in into position `x`, I think my problem is with moving the elements after `x`.

When I call `linkedlist.insertAt(2, 50);`, it's doing: `10, 20, 50, 30, 30`, but expected: `10, 20, 50, 30 ,40`.

Definition of `Node`:

```
struct Node {
    Node * previous;
    Node * next;

    int id;
    int data;
};
```

Comment: Just for completeness, can you show us the definition of `Node`? Other than that, I just wanted to comment that this is a pretty well-written question for (ostensibly) a homework problem -- it shows the code having the issue, what you did, expected output, and actual output. Other students with homework questions would do well to mimic this question.

Comment: Added in definition of `Node` there.. Ya it is homework and bin bugging me for last week so i said i would try here for some help

Comment: The loop looks wrong, it loops on `i` but `i` is never referenced.

Comment: It looks like you got everything wrong here.

Comment: @Johnny993 - If the `insertAt` function is 0-based, you have an issue if `x` is 0.  Maybe you should rethink that entire loop knowing that you could insert before the first item or after the last item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++){
    vecList[x + 1]->next = vecList[x]->next;   // tranfer the address of 'temp->next' to 'temp'
    vecList[x + 1]->data = vecList[x]->data;
    if (vecList[x] == NULL){break;}
}
```

You're iterating over `i`, but nothing in the loop actually reads `i`. So you're just doing the same operation `getSize()` times. I think you meant to assign `vecList[i + 1]` to `veclist[i]`. Also the lower bound of the loop shouldn't be `0`, it should be `x`. Which, for further clarity, the name of that variable should probably be `pos` or something similar.

Also be careful whenever you are referencing `vecList[x + 1]` or `vecList[x - 1]`. What if `x` is 0 or `vecList.size() - 1`? You will be pointing to an undefined object.